# Nominations for new TNB Room Owners

Tags: discussion, chat, moderation

In response to the [increase in off-topic discussion in TNB](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24680/66833), we've [decided to appoint more ROs](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61013037#61013037). Here's how we'll be deciding the new room owners:

- For one week (until 14:00UTC, on the 15th of May 2022), nominations will be accepted as answers on this meta post. You may nominate any user, including yourself, and if you are nominated by someone else, please indicate whether or not you accept the nomination as a comment under the nomination or via some reasonable method.
- After the nominations period, an election will be held lasting one week. This will be on a separate meta post.
- Once the election ends, the top nominees with the highest scores will be reviewed by the current room owners and moderators for approval and instatement as new room owners. Currently, it is likely that the top 2 nominees will be appointed; however, if the current ROs and moderators decide otherwise, the number appointed may change (though it's unlikely to be less than 2).

In each nomination, please include:

- The user being nominated, along with a link to their profiles (both main and chat)
- Common active times in chat
- A short blurb about why this user would be a good room owner

Please post nominations for separate users as separate answers.

Votes in this thread will have no bearing, but feel free to vote how you want here.

Comment: How do I find my active hours?

Answer (score 17):

## <sup>Self</sup> Nomination for lyxal

- [Chat User Profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/354515/lyxal)
- [Main User Profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850/lyxal)
- Active between: 9am AEST (11pm UTC) to 12am AEST (2pm UTC the next day) (see below)

[image]

### Talking Points About Why I Should Get Your Vote

- Fun fact: this is my second time running for Room Owner of The Nineteenth Byte (my first run obviously didn't go so well). Clearly, I've got the determination to commit to helping moderate this site's primary chat room.
- Also fun fact: I live in the land of upside-down (aka Australia), meaning that while the current 4 RO's are asleep or doing other things during the night, I'm awake and able to moderate if need be.
- My idea of chat moderation is to roll with the conversation and either a) suggest topic changes or cut off a topic if there's a risk of noise or b) move the conversation (both retroactively and literally) to a different room. That way, the culture of TNB isn't lost and people don't have to constantly be
  wondering if they're off-topic. Off-topic is perfectly fine in small doses, and chances are that I'll be injecting bad puns and tasteful irony into
  conversations myself where appropriate.
- When it comes to moderation, I've had plenty of experience through managing Vyxal - being the owner of a growing golfing language and GitHub organisation
  sure does allow you to practice keeping things on-topic and organised.
- On the topic of managing Vyxal, you can trust that I'll be "sensible" as a Room Owner, because, as hyper-neutrino said, [the amount of trouble an RO could cause [TNB] is a lot less than the amount of trouble we could cause them should they intentionally try to commit abuse](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=61013206#61013206).
- And on the topic of other moderation experiences, I've RO'd 36 other chat rooms, so I sure do know how the different RO features work.
  Bad RO behaviour on my part would reflect badly on Vyxal and would consequently tarnish the work of many people who have invested heaps of time.
- I've seen the last 1000 consecutive days of code golf activity. That means I've
  seen how chat culture has evolved over time, and I have a pretty good idea of what the community views as on and off-topic.
- Speaking of constant activity, I'm in the [frequently in room list](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/240/the-nineteenth-byte?id=240&tab=general&users=frequent) for The Nineteenth Byte
- Also speaking of constant activity, my chat stats are similar to those of the current ROs last election; if those stats were good enough for them to win,
  they're good enough for me too :p
- I understand that we are all only human - if any of y'all do anything stupid in TNB or get too off-topic, I ain't holding that against you after the
  issue is resolved. Every incident/mistake is a learning opportunity and you continue on continuing on.
- Indeed, to quote everyone's favourite artificial intelligence GLaDOS: "there's no sense crying over every mistake - you just keep on trying until you run
  out of cake".
- In response to the call for [less noise in TNB](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60937502#60937502), I proactively created noise-overflow rooms to help provide alternative locations for off-topic conversations to be relocated.
- In summary, I'd be a strict-when-necessary-otherwise-chill Room Owner using the experience I've gained from managing projects such as Vyxal.

If you want to ask me about any of the above talking points or get further elaboration on why they're relevant, don't hesitate to ask in TNB.

Comment: By "roll with the conversation," do you mean you'll participate in it but try subtly shift it back on topic or just jump in and add to the conversation?

Comment: @user I mean that if it's appropriate, I'll potentially join in and if needed move the conversation later. And if there's an on-topic conversation someone wants to have, I'll suggest that takes precedence over the off topic conversation and move/make a new room for the off topic

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 16):

## [pxeger](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/475866/pxeger) (self-nomination)

Active hours (UTC), as decided by chat itself:

[image: graph of my SE chat user activity]

Essentially, on-and-off during the UK daytime.

I aim to be proactive in cleaning up the room:

- stopping or moving off-topic conversations and noise as appropriate
- clearing unnecessarily starred messages and no-longer-relevant pinned messages from the starboard
- [butterising](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12538) spam
- Evidence: [1](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=61035237#61035237) [2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=60990791#60990791) [3](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=60989643#60989643) [4](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=unpin&user=475866&room=240) [5](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=58544522#58544522) [6](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=57971393#57971393) [7](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=61029733#61029733) [8](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=60102964#60102964) yeah, you get the point. If you want more, just search for relevant keywords [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=butterise&user=475866&room=240)

I've been an active member in TNB for about a year and a half, so I understand the room's culture and conventions. I try to remain a level-headed voice of reason, seeing both sides of an argument, including playing Devil's Advocate at times.

I'm familiar with SE chat's quirks, and with the room owner tools, having done [plenty of testing](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135840/the-louvre).

I've also been a room owner of [Vyxal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106764/vyxal) for some time; although I'm no longer very active there, I've never abused my position. I'm also the room owner of [ATO](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122645/attempt-this-online), but that probably doesn't count since it's my own room.

Answer (score 14):

## Self-nomination for emanresu A

- [Chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/497390/emanresu-a)

Active hours:

[image]

In other words, I'm usually quite active between UTC 2am-9am when all of the other ROs are asleep. I've only been active in TNB (or on CGCC) for just over a year, but I have a pretty good understanding of the room's culture.

I'm a RO of [Vyxal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106764/vyxal) and more recently [canvas](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135246/canvas), so I have experience with the RO tools and how to use them - there's a reason why [the Vyxal Bot is frequently in Trash](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/82806/trash). I have >10k rep so I can handle chat flags.

My username's pretty much [set in stone](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/233294).

In my opinion, it's quite hard to judge what's "off-topic" and what's not. I don't see any point in creating general noise overflow rooms that are just going to freeze over, but conversations that do have relevant rooms should be moved to those.

I [occasionally](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=60168167#60168167) [poke](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=60008638#60008638) [ROs](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=60322057#60322057) [to](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=60655723#60655723) [do stuff](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60319849#60319849), although they do a fine job on their own.

One concern is that I used to have [a sockpuppet account](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/538692/allxy) that I used at school. I've figured out how to use this account while at school, so that shouldn't be a problem any more.