# Vote for the new TNB Room Owners!

Tags: discussion, chat, moderation

[The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) is getting new room owners. You've had a week (and a couple of hours) for [nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24731/66833), and now it's time to vote. In alphabetical order, here are the nominees:

- **emanresu A**
  [chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/497390) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/u/100664) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/u/100664) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24734) | [vote here](/a/24772)
- **lyxal**
  [chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/354515) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/u/78850) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/u/78850) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24732) | [vote here](/a/24773)
- **pxeger**
  [chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/475866) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/u/97857) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/u/97857) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24733) | [vote here](/a/24774)

Each candidate has a community wiki answer below. You may vote on as many as you want, and the candidates are welcome to vote as well, including for (or against) themselves.

Voting will close in a week (15:30UTC, Sunday 22nd of May). At the end of the election, we (the moderators and existing room owners) will review the votes and appoint either the two or three highest voted candidates (this does mean that, potentially, all candidates can be appointed).

Best of luck to all candidates!

**Important note**: serial voting detection applies to meta as well. If you vote for several candidates within a short span of time, your votes may be automatically cancelled. Make sure you check back before the voting period closes to make sure your votes went through.

Answer (score 19):

### [emanresu A](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/497390)

[image]

[chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/497390) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/u/100664) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/u/100664) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24734)

Chat user since 2021-02-04.

588 messages this week. 683 messages last week. 603 messages per week.

Answer (score 19):

### [lyxal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/354515)

[image]

[chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/354515) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/u/78850) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/u/78850) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24732)

Chat user since 2018-05-31.

861 messages this week. 931 messages last week. 801 messages per week.

Answer (score 19):

### [pxeger](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/475866)

[image]

[chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/475866) | [main profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/u/97857) | [meta profile](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/u/97857) | [nomination](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24733)

Chat user since 2020-08-21.

154 messages this week. 231 messages last week. 219 messages per week.