# Congratulations to the new TNB Room Owners!

Tags: discussion, chat, moderation

[Voting has closed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24771/66833), and, with the votes being a dead tie, all three candidates have been elected as room owners for CGCC's main chat room, [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte):

[image] [image] [image]

They have been appointed, effective immediately. Please welcome them as our new room owners and join us in thanking them for volunteering.

In the words of Dennis and hyper-neutrino, may the odds be ever in their favor.

Answer (score 8):

Haha italic names go brrr.

But /srs very cool. Can't wait to do a good job of ROing TNB.